# Documentation on how to use 'coroutines support for room'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

The page [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components) says that coroutines now has support for room and they have given the dependency as

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$room_version"
```

But I cannot find any documentation or code sample on how to go about using it. Any leads here?

Answer (score 1):

For now this article seems to be the closest thing available to an "official" guide on this topic:

[Room  Coroutines by Florina Muntenescu](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5).

Also, I have used `room-coroutines` in [this](https://github.com/aksh1618/Bitotsav-19) project, but can't guarantee that the usage is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

there is no straight forwards docs for this part. 
I used this feature on an ongoing project it almost like using the orignal coroutin 
Take a look on this [codeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..ads18&viewga=UA-69243313-1#0)
and also this [article](https://medium.com/@kyle.dahlin0/room-persistence-library-with-coroutines-cdd32f9fe669)

Comment: Note that the *article* is about an older coroutines API. I suggest waiting for a better resource.

Comment: I am in line with you this article is about older coroutines but it is usful to build things increamentally by apply the available part now then refactoring for better preformance and enhancements @Alex.F

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `suspend` modifier to your DAO like so:

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    suspend fun getAllWords(): List<Word>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Usage example can be:

```
uiScope.launch {
            val words = WordRoomDatabase.INSTANCE.wordDao().getAllWords()
            //Print all the words
            words.forEach { Log.v(TAG, it) }
        }
```

Examples adapted from the [Room codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin)